# Beginner questions about time series models and testing

Tags: time-series, econometrics

I have 2 questions regarding time series, I'm still at the beginning of my class, so we didn't go through more advanced or ML methods.

1, If I have a very obvious seasonality, let's say monthly, and I put the months as dummy variables, how do I choose the reference category? Is there any rule of thumb for this?

2, How do I test how good an OLS time series model is? Does BIC, or  adjusted R^2 still work? Or is plot

Comment: Regarding #1, as mentioned in an answer there is no real rule for this but sometimes it can make sense to choose the month with the smallest seasonal value or the one with the largest seasonal value or the one with the middle seasonal value.

Answer (score 0):

1. Regarding the choice of reference category, there is no rule of thumb for the choice of reference category. The reference category is picked according to different tasks.
2. You need to validate the stationary assumption for time series data, then configure a set of p,d,q with the smallest BIC or AIC values. In the case, autocorrelation and partial autocorrelation plot of data are useful to determine the values of p and q.